# ReferenceError: CryptoJs is not defined

Tags: javascript, hash, md5, cryptojs

I tried to hash a text in client-side. I used following code to hash it, but it shows this Reference Error.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/md5.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var plaintext = "hiii";
    var encrptedText = CryptoJs.md5(plaintext);
    alert("Encrpted Text : " + encrptedText.toString());
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There’s an error in the JS file itself.

Comment: the variable is named `CryptoJS` not `CryptoJs`

Comment: If you try to evaluate the script in the browser console, you get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lib' of undefined`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the entire package - not just the md5 module - change the `src` in your `script` tag

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js"></script></head>
<body>
<script>
var plaintext="hiii";
var encrptedText = CryptoJS.MD5(plaintext)
alert("Encrpted Text : "+ encrptedText.toString());
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If for you important the size of extended libraries, that you can use [pure-md5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pure-md5) (4.76kb) instead `crypto-js` (187.44kb).

```html
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pure-md5@latest/lib/index.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var plaintext = "hiii";
    var encrptedText = md5(plaintext);
    alert("Encrpted Text : " + encrptedText.toString());
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```